# Solution to form insertion dilemma

Tags: php, forms

I'm building a virtual tour application and have hit a bit of a stumbling block during the setup process.  Currently, the administrator is the one responsible for determining which stop belongs to which panorama as well as the choices for the next move.  In order to complete this, I need to be able to insert the photo name into the database along with the other information of the current stop.

My form solution was to add the photo names of a certain directory into an array, count the number of images in the folder, and create the corresponding number of mini-forms on the page.  Each form has its own save button that works via ajax, so all information is updated as the user works through the stops.

My issue has to do with adding the photo name via the submit process.  The photo itself is not a user-defined field in the form, and I'm using POST to pass the variables to the insert function.  Is there a way to include the filename in the $_POST array just before submission?

Comment: im not sure what you are exactly trying to do, but you can put the file name in a hidden input

Comment: @Jarry, I didn't know about that, thanks!  If you make it an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have to do its use a hidden input with the filename in the value attribute.

```
<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="the filename" />
```

also, you can add the filename as a parameter in the ajax call, but i think that the input its cleaner.